# How to setup AD DNS in split brain mode just for one host

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, internal-dns, dns-zone

I am sorry for imperfect terminology (have only very basic understanding of network administration).

I have two DNS:

- Public DNS which manages zone 1
- Internal DNS (which is AD DNS based on Windows Server 2012R2) which manages zone 2.

I need to change it to do a split-brain DNS for zone 1. However, I don't want to have a whole zone 1 in both DNS.

All I need is resolving just one host from zone 1 on internal DNS to internal IP and forward everything else zone 1 related to public DNS.

My question is how to configure it on this AD DNS, Windows Server 2012R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a zone for the name that you want to resolve. For example:

`cloud.joewebster.com`

Then create an A record in the zone leaving the name blank (same as parent).

See my screenshots for an example:

[image]

[image]

So `cloud.joewebster.com` is resolved to the internal ip address and all other DNS records in the `joewebster.com` DNS zone are forwarded externally to the public DNS servers that host the `joewebster.com` DNS zone.